# How to 'noindex' a specific image on a specific page on my website?

Tags: html, noindex

I'm generally aware how the noindex HTML tag works and how to use it. However, I haven't managed to find a way to not index specific images on specific pages on my website.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to add this particular no-index tag only on the specific pages.

I'm ***not*** looking for a solution where I would have a central file in which I would need to add the path of each new page for which the image on it should not be indexed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [noindex X-Robots-Tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#using-the-x-robots-tag-http-header) in HTTP header request.

Comment: You can use "noimageindex" in the header's meta tag, but it blocks all images on the page.  What if you put the images you don't want indexed in a special sub directory and blocked the directory?